# How to send data from android Activity to java class?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I am doing a simple app that get data from `editText` then it get that text and send to java class ( in the class I need it to convert string to utf8 encoding). What shall I do to send data from the activity and how can I receive it in the java class?

This is my UTFencoder Class:

```
public class UTFencoder {

public void main(String[] args) {

      String testString = encodeStringToUTF8("this is my app ... eskadenia");
      System.out.println(testString);
}

public static String encodeStringToUTF8(String stringToEncode) {
    String newValue = "";
    List<String> charactersCode = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        byte[] stringBytes = stringToEncode.getBytes("UTF-8");
        for (int i = 0; i < stringBytes.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println("utf value is " + stringBytes[i]);
            String value = String.valueOf(stringBytes[i]);

            int no = Integer.parseInt(value);
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(no);
            //System.out.println("Hex value is " + hex);
            for (int j = 0; j < hex.length(); j++) {
                charactersCode.add(String.valueOf(hex.charAt(j)));                  
            } 

        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot encode " + stringToEncode
                + " to UTF-8, UnsupportedEncodingException");
    }

Iterator iterator =charactersCode.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Object element= iterator.next();
    System.out.print(element+" ");




}

    return newValue;
}

}
```

Comment: An [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is also a Java class. So you can just call your method from within the [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).  Refer [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) to start writing your Android app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option 1:In android you can send data through Intent or Intent followed by Bundle.Like

```
Intent i = new Intent(current_class.this, linked_class.class);
   i.putextra("Key", value);
```

And get the value(suppose string value) in another class like:

```
  String value = getIntent.getExtra("String key which you used when send value");
```

But for your question you as I am not sure it helps or not, but you can use a global static variable in your activity class and assign which value you want to send in your method.. like

Option 2:

```
 class A{

   public static String _utfValue = "";

   void sendValue(){
       _utfValue  = "some value";
    }
 }
```

And fetch this value in your java class like:

```
  String value = A._utfValue ;
```

Option 3: You can use SharedPreference to save the value and get it from other class.

Option 4: You can use a static method with some return value and fetch the method in your java class through class name.

All the options are rough here. So just check this ,hope one of these will help you .

Comment: glad to help you dude.. all d best